# How to get webgraph in Apache Nutch 2.x

Tags: java, apache, web-crawler, nutch

I am using apache nutch 2.3.1 to crawl few websites.I have to find webgrapg of crawled data but unfortunately there is no class defined in this version as in version 1.x. Can some one guide me about this.
Following are complete command line option for version 2.3.1 ( but there is no webgraph)

```
Usage: nutch COMMAND
where COMMAND is one of:
 inject     inject new urls into the database
 hostinject     creates or updates an existing host table from a text file
 generate   generate new batches to fetch from crawl db
 fetch      fetch URLs marked during generate
 parse      parse URLs marked during fetch
 updatedb   update web table after parsing
 updatehostdb   update host table after parsing
 readdb     read/dump records from page database
 readhostdb     display entries from the hostDB
 index          run the plugin-based indexer on parsed batches
 elasticindex   run the elasticsearch indexer - DEPRECATED use the index command instead
 solrindex  run the solr indexer on parsed batches - DEPRECATED use the index command instead
 solrdedup  remove duplicates from solr
 solrclean      remove HTTP 301 and 404 documents from solr - DEPRECATED use the clean command instead
 clean          remove HTTP 301 and 404 documents and duplicates from indexing backends configured via plugins
 parsechecker   check the parser for a given url
 indexchecker   check the indexing filters for a given url
 plugin     load a plugin and run one of its classes main()
 nutchserver    run a (local) Nutch server on a user defined port
 webapp         run a local Nutch web application
 junit          runs the given JUnit test
 or
 CLASSNAME  run the class named CLASSNAME
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this feature is not yet added to the 2.x branch of Nutch, as a general rule I believe that the 1.x branch has more features and performs better (althought this is changing). If you need to stay on 2.x then I recommend that you either implement the feature by your self or perhaps migrate the `links-indexer` plugin from 1.x to 2.x (I believe that migrating the indexer plugin will be easier). I had this planned but couldn't find the time.